# Chrome extension webrequest redirect after executing code that takes 4/5 seconds

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, redirect, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome extension that executes some code (takes about 4 seconds) and afterwards does a callback that redirects the user to a page. However, no redirect takes place with the following code:

```
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
    functionThatTakes4Seconds(function(){
            return {
                redirectUrl: redirect
            };
    );
}, {
    urls: ["url.com"]
}, ["blocking"]);
```

When I don't run the function that takes 4 seconds the redirect works:

```
 chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
            return {
                redirectUrl: redirect
            };
}, {
    urls: ["url.com"]
}, ["blocking"]);
```

Does it timeout? Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't `return` from asynchronous code.

If you do return a blocking response, it must be returned synchronously; Chrome will not wait and you don't get a callback to call asynchronously.

> If the optional opt_extraInfoSpec array contains the string 'blocking' (only allowed for specific events), the callback function is handled synchronously. That means that the request is blocked **until the callback function returns**.

E.g. if your code took 4 seconds to complete but was synchronous, you could return the value from it and do this:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function(details) {
  return {
    redirectUrl: functionThatTakes4Seconds() // must return something
  };
}, {
    urls: ["url.com"]
}, ["blocking"]);
```

But you can't do an asynchronous call and have Chrome wait for it.

Compare to [Messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#event-onMessage): there you get a callback `sendResponse` that you can potentially call asynchronously. But not here.